# ng build -- prod fails (ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Unsupported import syntax' but ng build works fine

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I use 'ng build --prod' (or 'ng build --aot') I receive the following error:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule' 
Unsupported import syntax
```

What's interesting is that using the 'ng build' command works just fine.

I'm a little bit lost as where to look for the error or how to get a more specific error message.

In some components, I use an import syntax likethis:

```
import TemplateEditorcomponent = require("./components/admin/templateEditor/templateEditor.component");
import TemplateEditorComponent = TemplateEditorcomponent.TemplateEditorComponent;
```

Is this the reason why it fails (the use of 'require' function)? If so, why does 'ng build' work fine?

I'm using angular-cli 6.0.3

Comment: Why can you just do `ìmport { 'component' } from 'somemodule'`

Comment: It's an inherited project with LOTS of imports like that, I'm now in the process of changing all the import statements.

Comment: Yeah thats the best to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng build --prod` flag makes the compilation a bit stricter, cause it tries to run some more optimizations on your final code, to make it smaller and faster to deliver when it's deployed.

The additional errors you see are most probably the result of the `treeshaking` proces where it tries to determine if there's unused pieces of code. Therefor it walks over all your code and imports.

The import statement you used there is indeed false, but when run through `ng build` runs in the terminal under `node`, where `require()` is a valid `import statement`. I don't know the exact reason why the compiler starts complaining about this specific way of building, cause it should also run under `node`, but there's most likely a good reason for that.

The default way to import `Angular` component (prefixed with the `@Component()` decorator) is this:

`import { TemplateEditorModule } from './components/admin/templateEditor/templateEditor.component';`

Final note I'd like to add, judging from the relative path I'm seeing; you may want to consider setting up an `AdminModule` containing all your admin related components, services, etc., and then importing `AdminModule` into your `AppModule`.

This makes the optimization even better, cause your `AdminModule` can be lazyloaded/dynamically loaded. Just food for thought.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the meantime, I have set up a new ng project using angular-cli and change one of the imports to use the require() function, which resulted in the same error I have seen before. So I'm pretty confident this is what the issue was.

Comment: Excellent! If you're using the CLI, using the magic of `ng generate module moduleName` will keep your app in line with the convention that the Angular team supports. This way it'll be easier to detect when you're doing something they're not expecting.
If you could mark the answer as correct, that'd also be highly appreciated!